# Arch does not mount btrfs array on boot

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, btrfs

As data partition I have a multi-disk btrfs filesystem. My root disk is ext4

Fstab:

```
UUID=290624c6-6b95-41fd-94a1-923ebca64b83   /           ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 1
/dev/sdc    /mnt/btrfs  btrfs   rw,relatime,compress-force=zlib,autodefrag  0   0
```

When I boot the machine, it will wait for 1m30s with the message

```
A start job is running for dev-sdc.device
```

And after that

```
Dependency failed for /mnt/btrfs
```

When I do log in I can do

```
mount /mnt/btrfs
systemctl default
```

And it will work. The system will boot normally.

I first though I might need to do something with a mkinitcpio hook, but [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mkinitcpio-btrfs) says:

> Arch's default mkinitcpio package contains a standard btrfs hook, which is enough to get multi-device (RAID) support. Beside that, the kernel is capable of booting a single-device btrfs root without any hook

So everything should work out of the box.

Why doesn't it work, and what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 8):

Two comments. First, try to mount by Label or UUID instead of device. Device names can sometimes change.

Otherwise, `btrfs` requires `brtfs device scan` call before it knows about `btrfs` filesystems on your machine. I expected `arch` to handle this but somehow it didn't work until I created a service file for this and put it in `/etc/systemd/system/local-fs-pre.target.wants/btrfs-dev-scan.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Btrfs scan devices
Before=local-fs-pre.target
DefaultDependencies=false

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/btrfs device scan

[Install]
WantedBy=local-fs-pre.target
```

`DefaultDependencies=false` is necessary, otherwise it fucks up the boot. (Non-Arch users may have `btrfs` located in `/sbin` instead of `/usr/bin`)

This is what should be handled by `btrfs` hook (I figured that a bit later), but still, it is possible that there is a problem with that.

However you may have some other problem. That `Dependency failed` suggests that some earlier required service didn't start. I have no idea what that could be, you should check your `journalctl -b` and search for dependency complaints, it usually states what exactly is missing. Or at least, you get a chain of dependencies that failed - it is possible that dependency failures propagate...

You can also generate `systemd-analyze plot > boot.svg` and check the sequence what exactly booted in what order. You can guess from that what exactly went wrong - who was waiting for whom? And, what does `systemctl --failed` say?

Answer (score 3):

There is a hook for `mkinitcpio` that you can include to ensure

```
btrfs device scan
```

will run during boot before root filesystem is mount.

You can include this hook by modifying `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`, search for the line `HOOKS` and put `btrfs` in front of `udev`.

After modification be sure to regenerate initramfs by `mkinitcpio -p linux`

The Arch Wiki actually recommends using the `udev` hook, however I've got the same problem and is fixed this way.